# Component debugging props - react redux - Child component receiving non set values

Tags: reactjs, debugging, redux

I am debugging `react-redux` code written by a different person. While debugging, an aspect that was not working returned result like this

```
{"compare":null,"displayName":"Connect(Tag)"}
```

This is no set anywhere in the system, and making this fail.

My questions is - "How do I figure or debug what values are coming as props into a component from another component?"

Comment: if you want to debug your redux data then you can check in which reducer you are setting this {"compare":null,"displayName":"Connect(Tag)"} values and you can find which function going to set this value in reducer and then you can find component which uses that function.

Comment: I figured, that one of the values that was added in uppercase - ended up being the culprit. tag instead of Tag was causing the issues. I wonder how displayName got assigned, and why no error was thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing React dev tools. They have a react tree where you can see wich component came from where: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Also a great tool for debugging redux applications is redux-logger middleware where you can see all actions that were dispatched and track all state changes:
https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger (it is very easy to setup)

Hope this helps.